# how to split a string into array using preg_split with two condition

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, preg-split

I have a string like this : `x320h220`

I want to split this string into two variables : `$width` and `$height`

I Can split it using explode but I have to use this method twice to get these values so I found out `preg_split` will do the trick. But I don't know the Regex to split these string into two variables (find if string contain **x** then cut the rest till **h** and then cut the rest again in another variable) which they should be like :

```
$width = 320;
$height = 220;
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_match()`, not `preg_split()`. Use capture groups to extract the two numbers.

```
if (preg_match('/x(\d+)h(\d+)/', $string, $match) ) {
    $width = $match[1];
    $height = $match[2];
}
```

In the regexp:

- `x` and `h` match themselves literally
- `\d+` matches a sequence of digits
- Putting `()` around the digit sequence creates a capture group, so the matched portions are put into the `$match` array.

Comment: @Barmar Awesome dude. Can you explain the regex in your answer ? explain each one of them if its possible for you

Comment: @Mohammad I've added it, but it hardly seemed necessary to go into detail for such a basic regexp. It doesn't use anything advanced, so even a regexp beginner should understand it. You should go to www.regular-expression.info and read the tutorial.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

use this
$size = `preg_split("/[xh]/", "x320h220", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`

Hope it will work for you :)